# Find a positive integer $n$ such that $ϕ(n) = ϕ(n + 1) = ϕ(n + 2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

**I need to find a positive integer $n$ such that $ϕ(n) = ϕ(n + 1) = ϕ(n + 2)$ where $ϕ(n)$ denotes [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).**

*What I am given:*

(1) You may take $ϕ(n) = 2592$.

(2) $ϕ(2n) = ϕ(n)$ provided that $n$ is odd.

(3) $ϕ(p) = p − 1$ for p a prime.

*What I did:*

I thought that I can take in a value for $ϕ(n)$, so I tried to take $ϕ(n) = 2592$. I found that $ϕ (5187) = 2·6·12·18 = 2592$ So can someone verify that I meet all the requirements that I am give, and that my answer is correct.

Comment: Is this an arbotrary $\phi$ with porperties (1),(2),(3), or is it the well-known Euler-phi (which is at least not ruled out)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes it is the Euler-phi

Comment: Ah, I was just wondering because of the formualtion "Waht I am given"; after all (2) and (3) are well-known standard properties of $\phi$

Comment: What's your suggestion for $n$ ? Note that $2593$ is prime, and odd.

Comment: @Sary In my question I noted that I tried to take n as 5187 because it gave 2592.

Comment: What is $2\cdot 2593$ ? Then you will have found two consecutive numbers with the same $\phi$-value : that leaves two possibilities for the third one.

Comment: Is $5187$ a unique solution to the problem?  I used sieve of Eratosthenes modified to compute "S[k] = S[k]*(p-1)/p" to calculate the totient function, and found no other solution up to 200,000,000 (two hundred million).

Comment: @DanielV I think so.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the hint (1), we observe that $p=2592+1$ is prime and also $\frac{p+1}2=1297$ is prime. Hence together with your computation $$\begin{align}\phi(2p+0)&=\phi(p)=2592\\
\phi(2p+1)&=\phi(5187)=2592\\
\phi(2p+2)&=\phi\left(4\cdot \tfrac{p+1}2\right)=2\phi\left(\tfrac{p+1}2\right)=p-1=2592\end{align}$$

Comment: So what does $n$ equal to?

Comment: 5187. Am I right?

Comment: @MissNadine What do you suggest if you want to make $n,n+1,n+2$ behave like $2p,2p+1,2p+2$?

Comment: Okay so since $p=2592+1$ then $2p=5186$, so we should make $n=5186$?

Comment: So 5186,5187,5188?